# Rails render @model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick rails question. When I do this:

```
<%= render @users %>
```

Rails will search for

```
_user.html.erb
```

Is there option to render different file?

EDIT

I do not made custom partial - I use params[:action] to determine what kind of html I will render for partial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

```
<%= render partial: 'path/to/partial', collection: @users %>
```

Read more about this on [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: This doesn't work in my script. When i put user:@users - I have error in partial because it push all collection to user, not only one user.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I thought you wanted to render an individual user. Use `collection: @users` instead.

Comment: Yes, I want push only one user, not all users to one variable. I have something like this in js.erb "<%= render @users %> and this render _user.html.erb, for every user. But when I do :local => {user:@users}, it push all query to user variable in custom partial.

Answer (score 0):

Rails looks for a method on the model called `to_partial_path` to determine which partial to render. So you can override this method to define your own partial within the model logic. See #4 in this post: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/